Performance Comparison: Flutter Web vs Expo React Native Web for Social Media-like Web Apps
I want to build a social media-like application, which includes features like scrolling and commenting. I want to write the code once and run it on web and mobile so i want to ensure good performance on both web and mobile platforms. I understand that both Flutter and Expo React Native are capable frameworks for mobile development, but I am particularly interested in their performance on the web. Also i want the performance in terms of something like: loading and scrolling speed.
